# How to call Javascript function within multi-line alert box?

Tags: javascript, quotes, javascript-objects

I am trying to display an alert box onpageload which calls a previously defined function.  However, it is not displaying properly because the object properties, mycircle.retArea and mycircle.retCirc, are being displayed literally.

```
<body onload="window.alert('The area of the circle is: + mycircle.retArea()\nThe circumference of the circle is: + mycircle.retCirc()');">
```

I am guessing a problem with my quotes?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<body onload="window.alert('The area of the circle is:' + mycircle.retArea() + '\nThe circumference of the circle is:' + mycircle.retCirc());">
```